# How do I put different meta info for multiple pages in a single HTML file?

Tags: javascript, file, html

I am building a website that has multiple pages in one html file using different div elements. The code is similar to the code below. I need to have different meta descriptions and titles for each of the different pages in that one html file. Can this be done?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="Page1">
    Content of page 1
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">Show page 2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    Content of page 2
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page1','Page2');">Show page 1</a>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried putting different  in each of the div elements but Facebook just chooses one of them out of the document and uses it for all of the pages.

Comment: What you're talking about is not possible. Your use of "page" is a bit misleading. You don't have multiple pages. You have one page with multiple containers that are shown or hidden accordingly. The two are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JavaScript to modify the meta data that Facebook (or most other crawlers) will index from your pages. Most crawlers do not execute JavaScript, so only that meta data present in the raw HTML will be detected.

You must modify your meta data on the server, before the HTML is sent to the client.

Comment: Alright I figured it would be impossible. Thank you both for your help.